# module not found exception when I try to require uniqid in react-native

Tags: react-native

I want to check whether react-native supports 'uniqid' module.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/uniqid

I am doing a simple test. Included "uniqid": "^4.1.1" in "dependencies" in my package.json. Then ran the command:

```
"yarn install"
```

Then i added the below statements in App.js file:

```
var uniqid = require('uniqid');
console.log(uniqid());
```

I keep getting this error:

```
 "Module does not exist in module map" error.
```

I have tried the below options already:

```
 rm -rf yarn.lock
 rm -rf package-lock.json
 yarn cache clean
 rm -rf node_modules
 watchman watch-del-all
 yarn start
```

No luck.

Comment: and what if `npm i uniqid` and then `yarn start` ?

Comment: Hi @Cherniv thanks for your suggestion. But this also didnt work. I think react-native is not compatible with this library. So decided to use shortuid. That works !!